# Heroku Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I keep getting this error despite trying everything out in internet.
I'm trying to run my flask application on Heroku.

Below is my ProcFile

```
web gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 geeni:app
```

Below is my geeni.py file.

```
class ChargeUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        jsonData = request.get_json(force=True)
        stripeid = jsonData['stripeid_customer']
        currency = jsonData['currency']
        amount = jsonData['amount']
        apiKey = jsonData['api_key']
        try:
            stripe.Charge.create(amount = amount, source=stripeid, currency=currency)
            return jsonify({'Msg':'Charged!'})
        except:
            raise

api.add_resource(ChargeUser,'/')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I've setup my heroku push/login everything and have throughly followed tutorials. No luck..

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your Procfile should be `web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT greeni:app`. As currently written, Heroku would never see that your application is ready to receive inbound connections:

- The `127.0.0.1` interface would not receive any external network traffic. Instead, the `0.0.0.0` string does bind to the all external interfaces.
- Heroku passes the required port via the `$PORT` variable, which is usually 5000.

Remember - Heroku manages the "routing mesh", which receives the inbound HTTP traffic, then forwards it to your application. It assigns the address and port, which can't be hard-coded in your Procfile.